# LINQ: Evaluating a function where array elements are matched by index

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Say I have a function c[i] = f(x[i], y[i]). I have the input value arrays x and y of equal length and I want to calculate the values of array c in the end. How do I get that using LINQ?

i.e. without having to write:

```
c = new double[x.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
{
   c[i] = f(x[i], y[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) method, e.g.:

```
int[] x = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] y = { 4, 5, 6 };

var result = x.Zip(y, (i, j) => i + j);
```

or if you have already method with adequate params, simply use:

```
var result = x.Zip(y, Function);
// in this sample Function looks like:
static int Function(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `Select`:

```
var c = x.Select((x_i, i) => f(x_i, y[i]));
```

If `c` needs to be an `int[]` instead of `IEnumerable<int>`, append `ToArray` to the end:

```
var c = x.Select((x_i, i) => f(x_i, y[i])).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Zip method to calculate

```
int[] a = { 4, 2, 3 }; 
int[] b = { 9, 1, 0 };  
var result = a.Zip(b, (i, j) => i + j);
```